# Adding taxonomies to node gallery and using views to display

Tags: 7, views, migrations, media

I think the most important piece of information I can give is I am doing a migration from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 and I am resetting everything up. This gave birth to a few hiccups along the way. As a side note, all content was migrated using the drupal-to-drupal migration module.

I have a few taxonomies. Some of the vocabularies have terms. I am using Node Gallery to create and display galleries and I am also using views to display some views. Given this information, I have 2 problems:

1. The first is I do not know how to link node gallery to any of the terms. This would be the first thing I need to do. I need to link a gallery to a specific category or term.
2. The second problem might be a bit involved. I need to create a view, based on the taxonomy accessed. On the Drupal 6 website, the menu URL was say /category/vocabulary/term. When clicked it redirected to ex. /gallery-page/term where both terms are the same.

I know the Drupal 6 site used Taxonomy Views Integrator. Not sure if that was what created it. I haven't had any luck getting any of this to work.

I see the Drupal 6 version allows you to select a category when creating or editing the gallery, not sure if this is a custom module.

Any advice, module suggestions or anything like that would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

I think I have figured out how to set categories, was missing a field. Added it and can now select. Will edit again if fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a plan. I have ignored the redirection for now. What I did was set up a view for each gallery-page/term that there should be. Each view was linked to a specific term that each gallery item is associated with.

The term association was made by adding a field to the gallery content type using the field type term reference. This allowed me to set the terms required for each gallery.

After setting up each of the fields I wanted to display including the path and additional settings, I got it to work displaying only the galleries in a specific taxonomy.

The solution is actually pretty straight forward. I would have liked to have used arguments, however I couldn't get that working. At least the problems described above have been resolved.